# Unable to goto Backend

Tags: magento-1.8

I have just installed & when we try to go to admin after entering username & password it remains on same screen

Thanks

Comment: I think session expired shortly .just Try in different browser..

Comment: did you use as base url `localhost`?

Comment: we have given http://localhost/magento-1.8/admin

Comment: use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a virtual host and have the site running under a proper local domain (i.e. magento.local), not localhost.  As you have found you won't be able to login running under localhost.